# Magento custom order status in comments

Tags: magento

We are running Magento CE 1.8.1.  When adding a comment, I've noticed that our custom order statuses aren't available.  For example one of these is "part picked".  When a user enters a comment, this status changes to "processing" which is quite annoying.

[image: Comments History screenshot]

Is it possible to include custom order statuses in this drop down? Or alternatively, is it possible to stop Magento updating the order status when a user enters a comment?

Apologies if the answer is really obvious but I have scoured the internet with no luck!

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check order status in admin panel in magento 
system -> order statuses

There should be value in following manner:

[image]

Unassign other rows if you found with processing status.

Comment: Yep this was half-right.  I needed to unassign unwanted rows and assign a state to my custom status in order for it to appear in the dropdown